# steam item price - rawurlencode not working?

Tags: php, urlencode

im really struggling with my PHP script. It gets a number of Steam market item names from a database and tries to get a price from the Steam market.

When the links are generated by the script they dont seem to work. However, when i put them manually into the browser they work fine.

My code (sorry if its rough - im learning)

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `item_data` LIMIT 5";
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

foreach($query as $row) {
    echo $row['marketname'].'<br>';
    $itemname = rawurlencode($row['marketname']);
    echo $itemname.'<br>';
    $addy = "http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?currency=1&appid=730&market_hash_name=".$itemname;
    $price = json_decode(file_get_contents($addy));
    if($price->success == 'true') {
        if($price->median_price) {
            echo intval(str_replace(str_split('$.'), '', $price->median_price));
        } else {
            echo 'No median price set.';
        }
    } else {
        echo 'Unable to retrieve price data.';
    }
    echo '<hr>';
}
```

This results in the following output -

```
Tec-9 | Isaac (Field-Tested)
Tec-9%20%7C%20Isaac%20%28Field-Tested%29
Unable to retrieve price data.
AUG | Ricochet (Battle-Scarred)
AUG%20%7C%20Ricochet%20%28Battle-Scarred%29
Unable to retrieve price data.
Glock-18 | Bunsen Burner (Minimal Wear)
Glock-18%20%7C%20Bunsen%20Burner%20%28Minimal%20Wear%29
Unable to retrieve price data.
MAG-7 | Seabird (Minimal Wear)
MAG-7%20%7C%20Seabird%20%28Minimal%20Wear%29
Unable to retrieve price data.
Glock-18 | Bunsen Burner (Field-Tested)
Glock-18%20%7C%20Bunsen%20Burner%20%28Field-Tested%29
Unable to retrieve price data.
```

If i go to http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?currency=1&appid=730&market_hash_name=Tec-9%20%7C%20Isaac%20%28Field-Tested%29 (for example) in my browser it seems to load up fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Works for me, can you show whats in `$price`?

Comment: var_dump results in "NULL". Its simply not getting to the same location as the browser.

Comment: So it's obviously returning correctly, even though that's the json I was wondering if it was being translated to an array instead of class for you. The issue is with `$price->success == 'true'`. If you remove the query and target one item like `$itemname = rawurlencode("Tec-9 | Isaac (Field-Tested)");` do you still get the same result

Comment: You didn't happen to change the `json_decode` to having a second param of `true`, did you?

Comment: @Bankzilla if i get rid of the query and do as you suggest i get the same result of "NULL". I did not change the second param to true, should i?

Comment: Do you have error reporting turned on? What version of php are you using

Comment: Also why did you change your comment about what the output of `$price` was?

Comment: PHP version 5.4.39, display errors is turned off and i thought you meant what was supposed to be in $price (this is shown if you click the link).

Comment: Turn error displaying on and see where you've gone wrong in your code. Because your code works, so the issue is something with your system

Comment: Warning: file_get_contents(http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?currency=1&appid=730&market_hash_name=Tec-9+%7C+Isaac+%28Field-Tested%29): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 429 Unknown in /home/site/public_html/csgo/sadmin/index.php on line 50
NULL
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/site/public_html/csgo/sadmin/index.php on line 53